# How do I solve "anonymous class derived from observer" error with observer method in viewModel

Tags: java, android, observable, android-room

I have successfully used an observer method in `MainActivity()` that looks like this:

```
public void inputNameTest(String inputName) {
    myViewModel.inputNameTesting(inputName).observe( this, new Observer<List<MyRoomEntity>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<MyRoomEntity> myRoomEntities) {
            //Sets data in RecyclerView
            myAdapter.setList( myRoomEntities );
        }
    } );
}
```

This sets user-input data to `Room` query and displays query in `RecyclerView`. I would like to move the function to the `ViewModel` however, to keep the `View` from cluttering up.

In the `ViewModel` I get a red underline on `new Observer<List<MyRoomEntity>>()` that says `anonymous class must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method`

If I change the `Observer` to `new android.arch.lifecycle.Observer<List<MyRoomEntity>>()` (as suggested by `Android-Studio`) the red underline vanish.

I also need to pass an `owner` parameter instead of `this`. I manage this by passing `this` from `MainActivity()`

```
myViewModel.setOwner( this );
```

to my `ViewModel`

```
public void setOwner(LifecycleOwner owner) {
    this.mOwner = owner;
}
```

When I'm done, my `Observer` method in my `ViewModel` looks like this:

```
public void getUserInputName(String inputName) {
    repository.getUserInputName(inputName).observe( mOwner, new android.arch.lifecycle.Observer<List<MyRoomEntity>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<MyRoomEntity> myRoomEntities) {

            Log.d("TAG", "OBSERVED INPUT NAME");
            if(myRoomEntities != null) {
                for(MyRoomEntity item: myRoomEntities) {
                    Log.d("TAG ROOM ", "Input Name: " + item.toString());
                }
            }
            myAdapter.setList( myRoomEntities );

        }
    } );
}
```

No error is produced, but for some reason nothing is shown in the `RecyclerView`. I do get the correct `Log` output from the `Observer` method:

```
Input Name: MyRoomEntity{id=2, name='Joe', date='1/3/2015', from='12.30', until='13:00'}
```

So, if I write "Joe" in an `EditText` box and press a button, Nothing is shown in the `RecyclerView` but I do get the correct `Log`. If I keep the `Observer` method in the `MainActivity()` I get both the correct `Log` and `RecyclerView` output.

Don't know what's wrong, but it has to be something with the two changes I did with the `Observer` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by this implementation you throw all google's work to trash, because what you do is provide MainActivity reference to ViewModel class and the main point to use MVVM is to avoid this problem to be safe in case your activity or fragment is destroyed and be able to save the data state in case of screen ratation.
So don't move the observer code inside the ViewModel class it is not "cluttering up" the activity.

Comment: Ah, ok, so I just keep it in the `MainActivity()` then? Thanks @Maksim :)

Comment: Yes exactly, remember the main idea is to keep data isolated from UI layer. If it solve your problem please mark this as answer :)